# Why I'm not getting ConcurrentModificationException while removing element from ArrayList during iteration

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, fail-fast, java-failsafe

I am using the following code to loop through an arraylist and then removing one element from the arraylist.

Here i'm expecting ConcurrentModificationException. But didn't get that exception. especially when you are checking condition with (n-1)th element. Please help me. Below is my code.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        arrayList.add(5 * i);
    }
    System.out.println(arrayList);

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer temp = iterator.next();
        if (temp == 45) {
            /**
             * temp == 40 (then i'm getting *ConcurrentModificationException) why not i'm
             * getting ConcurrentModificationException if (temp == 45)
             */
            arrayList.remove(1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's not foolproof. The exception is thrown if modification is noticed, it's not always noticed.

Comment: If I change `45` to `25`, then the exception gets thrown.

Comment: use `iterator.remove();` instead to get rid of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation makes a best effort to detect concurrent modification, but there are cases where it fails to do so.

The `Iterator` implementation returned for `ArrayList`'s `Iterator` checks for concurrent modification in `next()` and `remove()`, but not in `hasNext()`, whose logic is:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}
```

Since you removed an element when the `Iterator`'s cursor was at the element before the last element, the removal causes `hasNext()` to return `false` (since `size` becomes equal to `cursor` after the removal), which ends your loop without throwing an exception.